# One, Two, Three Words

Tags: word-property

Each column has a group of words with a commonality. I call it 1, 2, 3 words.

What are they?

| 1 | 2 | 3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Twitter | Parler | Facebook |
| Roti | Pita | Chapati |
| Euro | Dollar | Pound |
| Two | Three | Five |
| Poetry | Prose | Novel |
| Quiet | Still | Silent |

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The commonalities are

> Words in the first column only use letters from the first line of the keyboard.
>  Words in the second column use letters from *both* the first and second lines of the keyboard (but not the third).
>  Words in the third column contain at least one letter from each of the three lines of the keyboard.